# OpenLayers 4 different layer

Tags: openlayers

I'm changing from OpenLayers 2 to 4 and I'm stuck with adding multiple layers.

This is my OpenLayers 2 code:

```
featlayer = new ol.layer.tile("Orders",wmsfeat,{layers: sQLayers,transparent:true});
```

And this my actual OpenLayers 4 code:

```
var layers = [
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: twSettings.wmsmap,
    params: {'LAYERS': wmslayer},
    ratio: 1.1
    })
})
];

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'mapdiv',
  view: new ol.View({
  projection: projection,
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseInt(setPos[0]),parseInt(setPos[1])], projection),
})
});
```

I'm trying to convert the featlayer in this way:

```
var featlayer = [
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: wmsfeat,
    params: {'LAYERS': sQLayers},
    ratio: 1.1
    })
})
];
map.addLayer(featlayer);
```

But I have some errors:

```
a.addEventListener is not a function at ol.js:47
a.eg is not a function at ol.js:120
```

Comment: I tried to remove layers and insert just featlayer and it work, the problem is the constructor that they doesn't work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<script src="resources/js/ol4.4.2/ol-debug.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="resources/js/ol4.4.2/ol.js"></script>`. The errors will be much easier to read. Just use `ol.js` to deploy the application.

`featlayer` should be a `ol.layer.Tile` object, not and array. Take the `[ .. ]` out. It should be:

```
    var otherLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: twSettings.wmsmap,
            params: {'LAYERS': wmslayer},
            ratio: 1.1
        })
    });

    var featlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: wmsfeat,
            params: {'LAYERS': sQLayers},
            ratio: 1.1
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [ otherLayer, featlayer],
        target: 'mapdiv',
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection,
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseInt(setPos[0]),parseInt(setPos[1])], projection),
        })
    });
```

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try your solution and the debug version.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work:

`ol-debug.js:31668 Uncaught TypeError: options.layers.forEach is not a function
    at new ol.control.OverviewMap (ol-debug.js:31668)
    at mapInit (traffweb_op4.js:183)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (traffweb_op4.js:1716)
    at fire (jquery-1.11.1.js:3119)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.js:3231)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.1.js:3443)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.11.1.js:3474)`

Comment: `ol-debug.js` is returning useful information. It is complaining about `ol.control.OverviewMap`, but there is no `ol.control.OverviewMap` in your code (in the question).
Try to use the minimal code to get those two layers up and running. Afterwards, add other controls.
If you need further help, it would be easier if you share your entire (minimal) example.